# There is a differentiable function from R to R that has a unique critical point that is a local maximum but still not have a global maximum?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, maxima-minima

You can define some discontinuities and then eliminate the global max, but there is some function that have a unique critical point, this critical point is a local max (or minimum), and this function don't have a global maximum or minimum? Can you give some examples or maybe a reason because is not possible?

Comment: If differentiable means differentiable anywhere you can't have discontinuities.  Do you mean differentiable except at (finitely many?) discontinuities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique local extremum is absolute extremum for continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725688/unique-local-extremum-is-absolute-extremum-for-continuous-functions)